# angular: filter not always working (strange behavior)

Tags: angularjs, filter, behavior

I am filtering a table by a column that contains names.
when i start typing the first name, it filters only after 3 characters, and for all the other names in the table it starts filtering right away, from the first character.

My code:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tableController as tableData">
         <table class="credit-limit-table">
              <tr class="table-head">
                  <th style="min-width:100px">
                      <a href="#" ng-click="predicate = 'UserName'; reverse=!reverse">Changed By</a>
                  </th>                  
              </tr>
              <tr class="filter-row">
                   <td><input id="txtFilterUserName" ng-model="tableData.userNameFilter"/></td>  
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="row in tableData.jsonData | filter:tableData.userNameFilter | orderBy:predicate:reverse ">
                  <td>{{row.UserName}}</td>
              </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

thanks,
Roi.

Comment: I have this exact same issue